# React Custom Hook Array dependency causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook `useSingleValueChartData` that takes in arrays of data ("goal registrations") and do calculations. I use the hook in different components, like this:

**SleepContainer.ts**

```
import React, { FC, useContext } from 'react'
import SleepDetails from './layout'
import { SingleValueChartData } from 'models/ChartData'
import { appContext } from 'contexts/appContext'
import { GoalType, GoalWithValue } from 'models/Api/ApiGoals'
import { ApiRegistration } from 'models/Api/ApiRegistration'
import useSingleValueChartData from 'hooks/useSingleValueChartData'
import useHandleTime from 'hooks/useHandleTime'
import {
    roundToPrecision,
    minMaxSingleValueChartData,
    minMaxValue,
} from 'components/Core/Utils/misc'
import { createGoalLineConfiguration } from 'components/Core/Utils/chartUtils'
import MinMax from 'models/MinMax'

const goalType = GoalType.Sleep

const SleepContainer: FC = () => {
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
    const { startDate, endDate, timePeriod, handleTimeChange, setTimePeriod } = useHandleTime()
    const { registrations, goals } = useContext(appContext)
    const dirtyValues = [-1]

    const goalRegistrations: ApiRegistration[] | undefined =
        registrations && ((registrations[goalType] as unknown) as ApiRegistration[])

    const converted: ApiRegistration[] | undefined =
        goalRegistrations &&
        goalRegistrations.map(reg => {
            const value = reg.value || 0 / 60

            return { ...reg, value }
        })

    const chartData: SingleValueChartData[] = useSingleValueChartData(
        converted,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        timePeriod,
        dirtyValues
    )

    // goal lines
    const goal: GoalWithValue | undefined = goals && (goals[goalType] as GoalWithValue)
    const goalValue: number | null | undefined =
        goal && goal.value && roundToPrecision(goal.value / 60, 1, null)
    const goalLines = goalValue ? [{ ...createGoalLineConfiguration(goalValue) }] : []

    // y axis domain
    const dataMinMax = minMaxSingleValueChartData(chartData)
    const yAxisMinMax: MinMax = minMaxValue([dataMinMax.min, dataMinMax.max, goalValue || 0], 0.1)

    return (
        <SleepDetails
            datesVisible={{ dateFrom: startDate, dateTo: endDate }}
            onTimeChange={handleTimeChange}
            data={chartData}
            goalValue={goalValue ? String(goalValue) : ''}
            goalLines={goalLines}
            yAxisMinMax={yAxisMinMax}
        />
    )
}

export default SleepContainer
```

The `registrations` comes from Context and being fetched from API earlier in another component.

The hook do transformations on the data and assigns the transformed data to internal state using `useState`. As you see the registrations passed in is also specified in the hook dependency array `[registrations, startDate, timePeriod]`.

**useSingleValueChartData.ts**

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import { ApiRegistration } from 'models/Api/ApiRegistration'
import { TimePeriod } from 'models/TimePeriod'
import { SingleValueChartData, GroupedChartData, ChartDataKeys } from 'models/ChartData'
import { isBloodPressureValue, isNumberValue } from 'models/helpers'
import { getDatesBetween } from '@liva-web/core/utils/date'
import { BloodPressureValue } from 'models/Api/ApiGoals'
import { isValidRegistration, cumulativeSumArray } from 'components/Core/Utils/chartUtils'

function getBloodPressureChartData(
    date: string,
    regValue: BloodPressureValue
): SingleValueChartData {
    const { systolic, diastolic } = regValue
    const value: [number, number] = [systolic, diastolic]

    return {
        [ChartDataKeys.Date]: date,
        [ChartDataKeys.Value]: value,
    }
}

function getNumberChartData(
    date: string,
    value: number | null,
    total: number | undefined
): SingleValueChartData {
    return {
        [ChartDataKeys.Date]: date,
        [ChartDataKeys.Value]: value,
        [ChartDataKeys.Total]: (total || 0) + (value || 0),
    }
}

function initialSingleValueChartData(date: string): SingleValueChartData {
    return {
        [ChartDataKeys.Date]: date,
        [ChartDataKeys.Value]: null,
        [ChartDataKeys.Total]: 0,
        [ChartDataKeys.Accumulated]: null,
    }
}

export default function useSingleValueChartData<T>(
    registrations: ApiRegistration<T>[] | undefined,
    startDate: moment.Moment,
    endDate: moment.Moment,
    timePeriod: TimePeriod = TimePeriod.Week,
    dirtyValues: T[] = []
): SingleValueChartData[] {
    const [data, setData] = useState<SingleValueChartData[]>([])

    const groupValues = useCallback(
        (acc, reg) => {
            if (isValidRegistration<T>(reg, startDate, endDate, dirtyValues)) {
                const date = moment(reg.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                acc[date] = { ...reg, value: reg.value || null }
            }
            return acc
        },
        [startDate, endDate]
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        if (registrations !== undefined) {
            const groupedByDate: GroupedChartData<SingleValueChartData> = registrations.reduce(
                groupValues,
                {} as GroupedChartData<SingleValueChartData>
            )

            const allDates: string[] = getDatesBetween(startDate, endDate)

            const chartData: SingleValueChartData[] = allDates.map(date => {
                const { value, total } = groupedByDate[date] || {}

                if (isBloodPressureValue(value)) {
                    return getBloodPressureChartData(date, value)
                }
                if (isNumberValue(value)) {
                    return getNumberChartData(date, value, total)
                }

                return initialSingleValueChartData(date)
            })

            const withCumulativeSum = chartData
                .reduce(cumulativeSumArray, [])
                // add accumulated value except for first value
                // use null instead of 0 (charts are filtering null values)
                .map((accumulated, i) => {
                    let result: number | null = null
                    const calculated = accumulated - (chartData[i][ChartDataKeys.Total] || 0)
                    if (i > 0 && calculated > 0) {
                        result = calculated
                    }
                    return {
                        ...chartData[i],
                        [ChartDataKeys.Accumulated]: result,
                    }
                })
            setData(withCumulativeSum)
        }
    }, [registrations, startDate, timePeriod])

    return data
}
```

Sometimes (like in `SleepContainer`) I would like to do a little data transform before passing it to the `useSingleValueChartData` hook, hence the mapping dividing values with 60 (`const value = reg.value || 0 / 60`).

But if I do this, the hook goes in an infinite re-rendering loop. If I don't do the mapping and just uses the `goalRegistrations` as is, the infinite loop doesn't happen.

I suspect that this happens because the mapping isn't done before passing into the hook, so when it's done, it re-triggers the hook, which triggers a re-render where the mapping starts over again...

Is this correct? And any ideas to what I could do to avoid the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Infinite render happens because when you transform `goalRegistrations` with `map` new array is created every time and assigned to `converted`.
So `useSingleValueChartData` hook gets a new `converted` array on every render, which later will be used inside of it as a second argument of `useEffect` hook (1st arg is callback, 2nd is an array of values to compare for equality):

`}, [converted, startDate, timePeriod])`

inner `useEffect` will see it as it gets new `converted` array every time, and will call its' callback every time, which will cause `setState` which in it's turn cause a rerender, hence infinite render loop.

To solve this problem you could use `json-stable-stringify` to convert `converted` into a string, and use that string instead of array

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. Can you be more specific? What is first and second argument of useEffect? `startDate` and `registrations`?

Comment: I've edited the answer and tried to describe what I meant in more detail

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by moving `convertToHours()` out of component (so it will not create a new function on re-render.

```
function convertToHours(registrations: ApiRegistration[] | undefined): ApiRegistration[] {
    return registrations ? registrations.map(reg => ({ ...reg, value: (reg.value || 0) / 60 })) : []
}

const SleepContainer: FC = () => {
    ...
}
```

I also "memo'ed" the value so it'll only get re-computed when registrations actually change.

```
const converted: ApiRegistration[] | undefined = useMemo(
    () => convertToHours(goalRegistrations),
    [goalRegistrations]
)
```

That finally stopped the infinite loop!!